# How to find/create a command to open any application with arguments in bash?

Tags: bash, windows-10

For example, when I use the following command:

```
$ code path/to/file
```

It opens up the specified file with vscode. It's clear, concise and the argument passed to it is used as expected

Are there commands like this (or a way to make them) for any program? I know `sh -c "/path/to/program.exe"` can open the program, but passing arguments doesn't always work as expected (`sh -c "/path/to/vscode.exe" "/path/to/file"` doesn't open the file with vscode for example) and it's not as clear

Comment: What's the context? Where are you trying to execute arbitrary commands from?

Comment: Add quotes to make the `sh -c` command work: `sh -c '/path/to/vscode.exe /path/to/file'`.

Comment: @JohnKugelman That missing quotes were a typo, I've tried with them and I get the same result. I'm not sure what you mean by context, I am executing this in a git bash terminal

Comment: Replace `" "` with one space.

Comment: If `/path/to/file` has `spaces` (whitespace) in it, you will need to ensure it is quoted. You may need to use an array. See [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050), and specifically [5. I'm constructing a command based on information that is only known at run time](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050#I.27m_constructing_a_command_based_on_information_that_is_only_known_at_run_time)

Comment: It’s entirely up to the implementation of each command line utility as to how it processes arguments such as file paths. You can’t change this universally. The input to `sh -c` must be a single word, you’re using two (quote once only). Also, If on WSL, I think you need `sh -c 'vscode.exe "$(wslpath -w /path/file)"'`.